# Can an alerting rule include a collection query?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

When using Query Based Flexible Replication, is it possible to use a collection query in the alerting rule? Anyone have an example of how to create such a rule if it is possible?

We'd like to add documents that need to be pulled to the replica system to a collection, instead of relying on a content-based alert like a word query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a more complete answer, here's what I've learned...it wasn't obvious (at least for me) from the documentation. I was getting lost between using the API to create rules versus using the XQuery library. I found it best for my purposes to not worry about using the API. This example is geared toward specifically using the `alert` library when setting up Query Based Flexible Replication.

1. Setup alerting for the CPF domain:

   ```
   xquery version "1.0-ml";
   import module namespace flexrep = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/flexible-replication" 
       at "/MarkLogic/flexrep.xqy";

   import module namespace alert = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/alert" 
       at "/MarkLogic/alert.xqy";
   (: Run against the content database :)

   let $domain-id := 12956765056276017188 (: There are functions to help get this programmatically :)
   let $alerting-uri := flexrep:domain-alerting-uri($domain-id)
   let $existing := alert:config-get($alerting-uri)
   return 
       if ($existing)
       then $alerting-uri
       else
           (alert:config-insert(
               alert:make-config(
               $alerting-uri,
               "qbfr",
               "alerting rules for QBFR",
               <alert:options/>
               )
           ), fn:concat("Alerting configuration created- ",$alerting-uri))
   ```
2. Create a log action in the alerting config

   ```
   xquery version "1.0-ml";
   import module namespace alert = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/alert"
       at "/MarkLogic/alert.xqy";
   (: Run against the content database :)

   let $alerting-uri :=
       "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/flexrep/12956765056276017188/alerting"
   return
       alert:action-insert($alerting-uri, alert:make-log-action())
   ```
3. Insert the rule for intended user

   ```
   xquery version "1.0-ml";
   import module namespace alert = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/alert"
       at "/MarkLogic/alert.xqy";

   let $alerting-uri := "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/flexrep/12956765056276017188/alerting"
   let $rule-name := "StackFlow-Collection-Alert-Rule"
   let $description := "Will alert on documents in the StackFlow collection"
   let $user-id := xdmp:user("my-username")
   (: The cts query in the rule can use any of the cts constructs! :)
   let $rule :=
       alert:make-rule(
           $rule-name,
           $description,
           $user-id,
           cts:collection-query("StackFlow"),
           "log",
           <alert:options />
       )
   return
       alert:rule-insert($alerting-uri, $rule)
   ```

I am putting together a topic on this in the documentation section and will try to post some more examples and such. For now, gotta move along with the project. Hope this helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work fine. I don't have an example handy.